# Firebase database rules for group-shared data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My webapp, like 99% of apps, has in db a collection of users. I can access user at /user/ so I setup rule to allow every user to access only its data.

BUT I need every user join a group

```
/user/34029380432
  - name: realtebo
  - group_id: 123
  - isAdmin: true


/group/123
   - a lot of shared data, all members can erad, only isAdmin can write
```

How can I setup a rule that allow only members of each group to read it and only admin members to write group data ?!

Of course I could swap side, movin member list, as array, under each group and setting, inside each group, one or more admin id.

But I am not able to compose javascript rule.

Comment: Assuming you're using the realtime database, please update your question with the JSON of your database (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Then also add the code of a read/write operation you want to allow, or want to reject. And finally, please include some of the rules you've already written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you could do is having a messages and users node within your group objects. You can access to parent object for that data node on your security rules and see if that user is a member of users object node by the use of exists()

```
/group/123
   - messages // a lot of shared data, all members can read, only isAdmin can write
   - users // list of user uids that are added to this group
   - admins // list of admin uids

"group": {
  "$groupId": {
    "messages": {
      ".read": "data.parent().child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
      ".write": "data.parent().child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
    }
  }
}
```